# Unable to start Camel Routes which are loaded from external XML

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have Camel routes in a file 'CamelRoute.xml'

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route startupOrder="1">
    <from uri="file:D:\Work\eclipse_workspace\dataEngine_GIT_2\src\data" />
      <unmarshal>
        <csv delimiter="|" quoteDisabled="true" />
    </unmarshal>
    <to uri="bean:csvProcessor?method=processNew" />
</route>

</routes>
```

Below is code where I am loading above routes & trying to run

```
CamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext();
Resource resource= new FileSystemResource("F:\\GIT\\data_acquisition\\src\\main\\resources\\CamelRoute.xml");

InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
RoutesDefinition routes = camelContext.loadRoutesDefinition(is);
camelContext.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());
camelContext.startAllRoutes();
```

but route doesn't start.

is something I am missing ??

**SOLUTION**

`CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();` was missing

Comment: Tell some more what is going wrong, what errors you see etc, and what Camel version you use etc. And use a debugger, just set a breakpoint and see if the routes instance looks okay from the debugger pov.

Comment: Also you need to start Camel itself, eg camelContext.start() before you call start all routes.

Comment: @ClausIbsen: Thanks for Pointing it out adding `CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();` worked