# Load Apache Camel route from external source

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to build a Java application that loads YAML DSL Camel Routes from an external source, ideally, a database. The idea is to give the possibility to edit those routes externally, refresh CamelContext, and reload routes when one of those is updated.
I noticed that the current Apache Camel 4 documentation at https://camel.apache.org/docs/ and dozens of examples **don't show how to load YAML defined routes to the CamelContext**.
The only solution I found, this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/67758794/8740422, looks a bit like a hack, with creating some kind of fake `Resource`.

Is Apache Camel not supposed to be used like that or am I missing something from documentation?

Answer (score 1):

So yes, it seems it is the only way to load a route from yaml to CamelContext in java application.

1. Make sure you've added this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-yaml-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version> <!-- your camel version -->
    </dependency>
   ```

2.Use `PluginHelper.getRoutesLoader(camelContext).loadRoutes(resource)` to load  routes to camel context.

3. By java doc Resource is something that "Describes a resource, such as a file or class path resource.". To make a resource from something you have in memory you can use
   `ResourceHelper.fromBytes("fake-resource.yaml", byteArray)`. This will wrap the byte array with InputStream and build a Resource out of it.

Full example:

```
byte[] targetArray = //load your yaml route from external source;
Resource resource = ResourceHelper.fromBytes("test.yaml", targetArray); 
PluginHelper.getRoutesLoader(camelContext).loadRoutes(resource);
```